# Annoying error "Missing method: public TypeOfResult ..."

Tags: fixtures, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I have a `DoFixture` in the package `be.acred.b2c.ws.creditRequest.service.MyFixture`

When I run a test using Fitnesse I get the following error message.

```
Missing method: public TypeOfResult 
getBeDotAcredDotB2cDotWsDotCreditRequestDotServiceDotMyFixture() { } 
OR: public TypeOfResult 
beDotAcredDotB2cDotWsDotCreditRequestDotServiceDotMyFixturee() { } 
in class be.acred.b2c.ws.creditRequest.service.MyFixture
```

I can see that I'm not the only one having that problem but I can't find a solution on the Web.

Ok, I could as well define that method in my fixture, but **I'd like to understand why it's there and if there is any cleaner way to get rid of that error.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the page code. The same structure works fine when I'm using a ColumnFixture instead of a DoFixture.

```
!*> Classpath
!pomFile C:\Users\otonglet\WORKSPACES\b2c\pom.xml@test
*!
!|be.acred.b2c.ws.creditRequest.service.MyFixture|

|init_request|1250.00|

|form_data|{some json data}|language|en_us|

|send_request|en_us|

|show|key|
```

Comment: Please post your test page.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I edited the question. There isn't much to show.

Comment: Possible that the HTML list generated  by the !pomfile plugin is confusing the FitLibrary parser - can you try running the test without !pomfile?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I did a test and the exact same HTML structure works when I'm using ColumnFixture instead of DoFixture.

Comment: Did you manage to get around this issue? My Fitness was working fine and suddenly it started giving me this error:(

Comment: @Rakesh yes, I used ColumnFixture instead of DoFixture (the question was modified actually). But this was in 2014. I'm not sure I could be of assistance today.